# Ignore List Wrapper Class When Unmarshalling SOAP Response

Tags: java, spring, soap, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I'm receiving a SOAP response (that I have no control over) that contains containers for every list in the response.

Example XML:

```
<account>
    <accountNum>12345</accountNum>
    <arrayOfAccountHistories>
        <accountHistories>
            <accountHistory>
                ... 
            </accountHistory>
            <accountHistory>
                ...
            </accountHistory>
        </accountHistories>
    </arrayOfAccountHistories>
</account>
```

When I generate code from this, I get objects like:

```
public class Account {

    private int accountNum;
    private ArrayOfAccountHistories accountHistories;

}

public class ArrayOfAccountHistories {

    private List<AccountHistory> accountHistories;

}

public class AccountHistory {

    ....
}
```

What I'd like to do is bypass the ArrayOfAccountHistories container and have:

```
public class Account {

    private int accountNum;
    private List<AccountHistory> accountHistories;

}
```

I'm using Spring's JAXB2Marshaller to handle the conversion. I've looked everywhere but I can't find a way to strip the ArrayOfAccountHistories from the WebServiceMessage before it's unmarshalled. I've also tried using different annotations on the generated classes, but I've had no luck there either.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!